# Apache2 .htaccess

Tags: apache2

I'm getting really frustrated today, while trying to just set up my development environement and start doing some actual work.

After installing php, apache2 and mysql over `apt-get install phpmyadmin` I'm trying since about an hour, to make .htaccess files work in my `/var/www/projectname/.htaccess`

I tried out multiple solutions, that basically told me to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` but none of them seemed to work.

What I tried:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    #AllowOverride All
    #AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=All, MultiViews        
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

The commented lines are what I tried, both didnt work. I either get a 500 internal error (when I set `AllowOverride All`) or the .htaccess doesnt do anything.

Can someone help me here? I need to get this to work, to finally start working :)

As side note, my knowledge with ubuntu or linux in common, is very slim - I just do what google tells me.

```
cat /etc/issue: Ubuntu 11.10
```

Comment: You should check your log files eg. using `tail -F /var/log/apache2/*.log`. There is often very valuable information in them.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to find out that mod-rewrite was missing `... Invalid command 'RewriteEngine' ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `AllowOverride all`.

The 500 error is occuring because there's a bug in the htaccess which is either causing an infinite loop and making apache get confused or doing something else weird. Most likely because of a typo. Paste in the htaccess file and we can have a look.

Also, run the command `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to ensure that the htaccess rewrite functions work.

Comment: You are right, it was mod rewrite missing - that caused the 500 internal error for the .htaccess file (I tested it on another machine at work, where obviously mod rewrite was active)

Answer (score 0):

When I get this error it usually is a permission issue make sure apache2's user/ group have read permissions on the files and execute permissions on the directory..

I think this could help a little. 
http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/servers/5270-apache-conf-html-permissions.html

Comment: That was my first tought too, I forgot to mention in my question that I already allowed the permissions accordingly with chown / chmod